# Number type from a polynomial type

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am writing some templated functions for polynomials.
They will input a polynomial, e.g.

```
template<typename polynomial>
auto evaluate(polynomial const& pol, polynomial::value_type x ) -> dectype(pol[0])
{
    // return Horner-Ruffini
};
```

The `polynomial` class can be just `std::vector<T>`, in which case I want `x` to be of type `T`, or other custom polynomial class.

What is a correct way to define this templated function. 
I am having trouble writing it properly for the case `polynomial = std::vector<double>`.

**Note:** The code above contains some of my guesses of how the type of `x` and the return type might have to be defined, but they don't seem to be correct.

Comment: `typename polynomial::value_type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably put some more thinking into the constraints on type `p` (i.e. is it acceptable to assume a `value_type` member etc.), but this works for your `std::vector` case:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename p>
typename p::value_type evaluate(p const& pol, typename p::value_type x) {                                                                                                        
  typename p::value_type result = 0;
  for (const auto& v : pol) {
    result = result * x + v;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<double> test{1, 2, 3, 4}; 
  std::cout << evaluate(test, 5.0) << std::endl;
}
```

You are missing a few `typename`s to let the compiler know expressions such as `p::value_type` are actually types.

Comment: I see. That is what Jarod42 was saying and that is one of the reasons I was having trouble. Thank you.